# How to properly isolate multiple rails applications in development (local machine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

Given we use a preferred flavour of a ruby version manager (RVM or Rbenv) the ruby gems are isolated per ruby version.

1. Let's say we want to work on multiple applications locally (they are completely separate applications) and we want to use the same ruby version and the same rails version how do we properly isolate them and their gems? Are gemsets the (only) answer here? I mean if I have 5 applications with the same ruby version and I keep adding gems on all 5 fronts it's just a matter of time when one of the applications is ok with the latest stable gem version while one of the apps will still need to roll on an older version of the same gem due to legacy dependency or whatnot. How do you guys avoid this timebomb?
2. What if we want to use the same ruby version on multiple apps but a different Rails version? Rails being 'just a gem' is the answer same as for the above?

Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly the problem that Bundler solves. When you do `bundle exec <something>`, it will use the gem versions specified in your `Gemfile.lock`. That means you can have as many versions of any particular gem you want, but it will select the correct versions per application when you start your app.

Comment: Thanks @JonCairns . So as soon as more than one local apps are sharing an exact ruby version and I want to avoid confusion, frustration and a broken heart I should **always** prepend `bundle exec` to **all** my commands? This is something I haven't been doing all the time so I guess I was just lucky not to hit an 'unexplainable' conflict so far...

Comment: that's exactly right, and yes, you can get away without doing it sometimes - lucky, as you say!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use:

- `rbenv` to handle multiple ruby versions on the same machine
- `bundler` to define the dependencies of each application

Make sure to push `.ruby_version`, `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to make sure every is using the appropriate version of each gem...